# QML ошибка "Model size" при создании FileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qml, viewmodel, qfiledialog

При открытии filedialog появляется данная ошибка:

```
Model size of -154 is less than 0
Model size of -9 is less than 0
```

Диалог такой:

```
FileDialog {
                id: topFileDialog
                title: "Open file dialog"
                folder: shortcuts.home
                selectFolder: true
                modality : Qt.WindowModal
                onAccepted: {
                    topEditbox.text = topFileDialog.folder
                 }
            }
```

С чем это связано и как убрать? Спасибо.

Comment: какая версия qt?

Comment: Данный варнинг был исправлен в версии 5.15 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-92444

Comment: Версия Qt 5.13.2